# (Why) does OLAF have authority to investigate whether FRONTEX engaged in illegal pushbacks?

Tags: european-union, borders, illegal-immigration

In a piece of news from [January 2021](https://www.politico.eu/article/olaf-opens-investigation-on-frontex-for-allegations-of-pushbacks-and-misconduct/) it was said that:

> The EU’s anti-fraud watchdog, OLAF, has opened an investigation into Frontex, the bloc’s border agency, over allegations of harassment, misconduct and migrant pushbacks, according to four EU officials.

The two agencies confirmed an investigation was talking place, but did not confirm/provide any other detail.

So, I wonder: to what extent can OLAF investigate such allegations, since they mostly involve [alleged] human-rights violations, but OLAF is an anti-fraud agency?

(The two agencies often cooperate, e.g. on [tobacco smuggling](https://ec.europa.eu/anti-fraud/media-corner/news/05-07-2021/olaf-supports-frontex-operation-against-tobacco-smuggling_en), so one investigating the other also seems odd.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OLAF's [mission](https://ec.europa.eu/anti-fraud/about-us/mission_en) includes investigation of corruption, including

> suspicions of serious misconduct by EU staff and members of the EU institutions.

More precisely, article 2(1) of its [establishing document](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A01999D0352-20160101):

> 1. The Office shall exercise the Commission’s powers to carry out external administrative investigations for the purpose of strengthening the fight against fraud, corruption and any other illegal activity adversely affecting the Union’s financial interests, as well as any other act or activity by operators in breach of Union provisions.
>
> The Office shall be responsible for carrying out internal administrative investigations intended:
>
> (a) to combat fraud, corruption and any other illegal activity adversely affecting the Union’s financial interests,
>
> (b) to investigate serious facts linked to the performance of professional activities which may constitute a breach of obligations by officials and servants of the Communities likely to lead to disciplinary and, in appropriate cases, criminal proceedings or an analogous breach of obligations by Members of the institutions and bodies, heads of the bodies or members of staff of the institutions and bodies not subject to the Staff Regulations of Officials of the European Communities and the Conditions of Employment of Other Servants of the Communities.
>
> The Office shall exercise the Commission’s powers as they are defined in the provisions established in the framework of the Treaties, and subject to the limits and conditions laid down therein.
>
> The Office may be entrusted with investigations in other areas by the Commission or by the other institutions or bodies.

Comment: Ok, so I guess it comes under "misconduct" and "breach of obligations by officials and servants of the Communities likely to lead to disciplinary and, in appropriate cases, criminal proceedings".

Comment: @Fizz misconduct certainly does (`;-)`), and I should think that the others do too, especially considering phrases like "illegal activity" and "breach of obligations."

Comment: This seems like a pretty broad mandate for the European Anti-**Fraud** Office.  In the correct-thinking US, that would be investigated by the Inspector General.

Comment: @RonJohn "What's in a name? that which we call a rose
By any other name would smell as sweet."  Inspector generals (the US seems to have one per executive department) do basically the same thing: they fight fraud and misconduct.  The name of the office doesn't much matter.  The EU's structure is rather different from that of the US, so the implementation details are also rather different, but, still, a name is just a name.

Comment: @phoog false analogy.  "Water" and "agua" both mean "the liquid form of the chemical compound H-O-H".  *Fraud*, on the other hand, just has **one** meaning: "an act of deceiving or misrepresenting".  (The "multiple" definitions at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fraud all center around deception and trickery for the purpose of getting something from someone else.)

Comment: @RonJohn my point is that naming something a "fraud office" doesn't mean that its mandate must be limited to investigating only crimes that literally constitute fraud.  If they want to use "fraud office" to denote the office that investigates any crime with potential financial implications, that's their prerogative (and the cognate of "fraud" may have a broader meaning in some official languages). Also, mandates change. Look at the US Secret Service, founded to fight counterfeit currency, now most visible in its role as the primary VIP security service.

Comment: "Look at the US Secret Service". Another false analogy, since they are the *Secret* Service, **not* the *Anti-Counterfeiting** Service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128634/discussion-between-phoog-and-ronjohn).